# UITableViewcell and an IBAction

Tags: iphone

I have a class: `@interface MyClass :UITableViewCell`  ... where I declare an -`(IBAction)myMethod`...

In the implementation of my class, I want to:

```
-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender
{
    MyOtherController *cont = [MyOtherController alloc]initWithNibName:...];
```

I want it so that when I click my button, I will see my new view (the view of MyOtherController),
How do you do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use

```
[newViewController presentModalViewController]
```

or

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

just write a function for that button pressed event to load the another view.